# AngularJS: $watchCollection does not work; throws error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a problem in AngularJS where `$scope.$watchCollection()` throws an error. I've reduced my code to the point where it's exactly the same as example code in the docs (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection), and the error is still thrown:

```
function OverviewCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.names = ['igor', 'matias', 'misko', 'james'];
  $scope.dataCount = 4;

  $scope.$watchCollection('names', function(newNames, oldNames) {
    $scope.dataCount = newNames.length;
  });
}
```

I get the error

```
'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$scope.$watchCollection('names', function(newNames, oldNames) {
  $scope.dataCount = newNames.length;
})')
```

I have no idea what the problem could possibly be. I'm doing exactly what the docs say, except I'm putting it in a controller, but it seems this code is intended for use in controllers. So what's the problem here?

Comment: What version of angular are you using? `$watchCollection` is a fairly new feature.

Comment: 1.0.6. The latest stable version seems to be 1.0.8.

Comment: upgrading to 1.2.0-rc2 seems to do the trick. Also had to explicitly include routeProvider to get the app working. (I wonder if that means I can drop routeProvider completely; I don't really want my views directly tied to urls.)

Comment: Yeah `$watchCollection` isn't in the stable builds (you can specify your version in the API documentation in the top left to see what you can use). Not sure about your `routeProvider` woes, though.

Comment: routeProvider was moved out of the core, so it has to be included explicitly. And I find myself wondering if I really need it. All the tutorials use it, but I don't really care about the bookmarkability of different views of my app. In fact, I want multiple views simultaneously. I don't know if Angular can do that, but that's for later.

Comment: Not the best place for this, but just a note on routes. You can only have one `ng-view`, which is why I skipped `routeProvider` and just use `ng-include`s.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that when I get to that point.

Comment: beware of going strictly by the reference docs for $watchCollection. The impl does NOT currently do what the docs say it does. See [bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621)

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the following syntax :

```
$scope.$watch('myCollection', function(value, oldValue) {
    // insert awesome code here
}, true);
```

The `true` parameter tells AngularJS to "deepwatch" the value.

Comment: How deep will it watch? There are basically two things I'm interested in: are any elements added to the list, and for each element in the list, there are a few properties I'm interested in, but not all. So I was planning a shallow `$watchCollection`, and then for each element a few specific `$watch('item.name')` and a deep `$watch('item.sublist', function, true)`. Or would a single deep watch perform better?

Comment: The point is : why would'nt you use deep watch ? It would answer your need (watch both array length and array's inner items' content), but could lead to some pitfalls. The main inconvenients with deep watch are its poor performance on huge objects or arrays, and the fact that it can lead to redundant $digest cycles and crash your app.

Comment: My model can end up pretty big. Not everything needs to be checked constantly. But more importantly, if I deep watch everything, and something changes, I still don't know what actually changed, do I? So I need to check everything again by hand. This, I think, will make deep watch utterly useless to me. Except for the item.sublist; if anything changes there, I'm going to redraw the whole thing.

Comment: Sorry for asking that, but why exactly do you need to watch all this stuff ? I mean, what would you do at each change of you model ? Maybe there's a better way to do this ?

Comment: I need to redraw parts of the vector graphics representation of my model. The model contains a lot of information, but only that sublist and probably the name will show up in the vector graphics representation.